# Selecting rows based on multiple columns in pandas - why are these two commands different?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas DataFrame:

```
import pandas as pd
a = [0,0,1,1,2,7]
b = [1,0,0,1,1,4]
df = pd.DataFrame(list(zip(a,b)), columns = ('a','b'))
df
    a   b
0   0   1
1   0   0
2   1   0
3   1   1
4   2   1
5   7   4
```

I want to select all rows where both **a** and **b** are greater than zero:

Why does this command only return some of the desired rows:

```
df[(df['a'] & df['b'])>0]
    a   b
3   1   1
5   7   4
```

While this other command returns all of the desired rows:

```
df[((df['a']>0) & (df['b']>0))]

    a   b
3   1   1
4   2   1
5   7   4
```

Comment: ```(df['a'] & df['b'])``` this returns a column as the sum of ```a``` and ```b```, which is executed first, and hence is what you are comparing if it's greater than 0.

Answer (score 0):

it would mean that sum should greater than 1?
do you also have negative values in these columns?

```
df[df.sum(axis=1)>1]
```

```
    a   b
3   1   1
4   2   1
5   7   4
```

OR

```
rows where values is greater than zero are summed along rows
df[df[df>0].sum(axis=1)>1]
```